# How to make a custom object page display under a Visual Force tab

Tags: apex, visualforce, tab

I know that by giving tabStyle="VFpagename__tab" the corresponding apex page displays under the VF tab i have specified , is there anyway i could make a custom object page to display under the VF tab

Comment: little confused on what you want!!

Comment: onclicking the links in the sideBar , under a VF page Tab , the corresponding apex pages or a custom object page should display